# Common structure for MIDI systems?

Tags: sound-effects, midi

I'm thinking of writing a MIDI system for my game that would take in an instrument and a note, then play a sound.

Considering so many rhythm games have already been made, I am curious as to how others have tackled this issue, so I might learn what things they considered in making a better system.

To be clear, I am not asking for opinions of 'which way is better', but rather, 'what have others done?'